# Excel | Formula to find total amount in this situation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

Assume that we are currently in the month **March**. I have a table with all the months and a list of products. Inside each column i have the number sales a product has made on that month, like so:
[image]

Notice i have a cell containing "Total until current month". I would require a formula to find out the total amount of sales of a specific product (product A for example) up until March (current month) as you can see with the manually typed 6, 1 in Jan and 5 in Feb.

I would usually do this by finding the sum of cell C4 and D5. But this should be 1 dynamic formula that is updating as we progress onto next month. So as an exammple, in April, it will find the sum of cell C4 - E5 (Jan - March) and update the value.

Is this possible?

Regards

Comment: If you have a complete column or row of numbers in a row to add, use AutoSum. Click into the cell at the end of the list you want to add (below or next to the given numbers).
In Windows, press Alt and = at the same time.
On a Mac, press Command and Shift and T at the same time.
Or on any computer, you can select the Autosum button from the Excel menu/ribbon.

Comment: @sonukumar You clearly did not read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a helper row above the month names that has the month numbers 1-12.

Then use SUMIFS():

=SUMIF($C$2:$N$2,"<=" &MONTH(TODAY()),C4:N4)

[image]

You could hide that row so it is not visible and not readily accessible.

Comment: This works but how does it not add the values of c2-n2. How does it know to stop at current month?

Comment: I would suggest to use `$C4:$N4` if you fixed the columns on row 2. also `MONTH($P$2)` for manually entering the "current" date, I suspect "current" is not quite `TODAY()` in all situations such as doing reports for just finished month

Comment: Look into [SUMIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) it will give a better explanation than I could, but in short the first two parameters tell the formula which column to add together.

Comment: @Aprillion yes one could lock the columns but since the OP only requested something that would copy down it was unneeded, I only lock everything on the first part because hitting F4 once is less work.  Also the OP said to Current month.  So yes if the OP wanted to make where he/she changed the month from Current to one of their choosing then a cell with a date in it would be required to be reference as you said.  But you are making assumptions that I try to stay away from.

Comment: I was easily able to change month to DATE and specify a date to simulate the future months. thanks!

Comment: all valid points.. I just work for internal customers so I won't get paid more if my solutions break after trivial user edits such as copying formula to display average in column Q or doing reports after weekend / before vacation / corrections for previous month :)

Comment: @Aprillion That's the difference, most of what I build is for me alone.

Answer (score 1):

In row 3 put month numbers. Now if in cell Q4 you have a month number that you want to relate to use:

```
=SUMIF($C$3:$N$3,"<"&$Q$4,C5:N5)
```

for sum of A and drag down for other products.

If you want to pick the product you want sum for and have it all in one cell, then assuming that in cell R4 you have your product name (e.g. "B") write

```
=SUM((C3:N3<Q4)*C5:N6*(B5:B6=R4))
```

and press ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: `SUMIFS` function would be more suitable without array formulas for Excel 2007+

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to leave **E4** through **N4** empty.  Only put a value in **E4** once March is complete and you have a value for March.  This will allow a formula like:

```
=SUM(C4:N4)
```

for *Product A*

Comment: Of course.. As stated i would usually do a sum. But in this problem, those fields cannot be left empty, it is not a possibility to leave it blank as it defeats the purpose of the spreadsheet. The scenario i gave was just a easy to understand example